# Adding number to class for jquery carousel slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this carousel code:

```
navFormatter : function(index, panel){
    return  {
        'class'  : ['slide1', 'slide2', 'slide3', 'slide4','slide5', 'slide6'][index-1]
    };                  
},
```

How do I dynamically generate the numbers?

I have tried:

```
navFormatter : function(index, panel){
    return  {
        'class'  : $(this).addClass("slide" + (i + 1))
    };      
},
```

Something like that?

Comment: `'class'  : 'slide' + (index - 1)`

Comment: Yay!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navFormatter : function(index, panel){
                 return  {
                  'class'  : 'slide'+index;
                };

        },
```

Should work.